# How to resolve a "Transient error" from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am building an app for a client using the Microsoft Grap API and when I log in with a particular account I get this error:

Request Id: d300b62e-e0a5-4f62-9957-1cc10fd42800
Correlation Id: e1912683-45cb-459e-b631-9706f6cd2479
Timestamp: 2020-04-20T07:51:51Z
Message: AADSTS90033: A transient error has occurred. Please try again.

I have tried 2 other accounts and they work without an error.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue or how I can start to work out what the issue might be?

EDIT:

Example of the URL being used to authorise the user

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientid>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<local_uri>&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&state=12345
```

Thanks,
Scott.

Comment: Please include your code snippet to investigate it accordingly.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Code example is difficult as I am browsing to the URL in the edited question and then receiving the transient error!

Comment: Hey Scott, are you still facing this issue?
This looks like a temporary issue that generally occurs when "MSODS is unavailable".
Please try again and let us know.

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity yes still getting this error and I was expecting it to resolve itself with it being a transient error. It is only with 1 account, 2 other accounts work fine!

Comment: @slarge Thank you for the response. Let me check with someone in my team and get back to you.

Comment: Can you share which accounts are working and which account is not?

Comment: What was the resolution? I am getting the same error on a couple of user accounts too.

Comment: @hamish it just started working. I didn't change anything! I may have reapplied permission that is it but I think I don't that a few times and it didn't work so the answer is I'm not sure what happened!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same in ÅppCenter.ms, today.

Answer (score 4):

For those that come here in the future, the best place to check whether or not the issue is isolated to just you, or is part of a wider issue is the official [Microsoft 365 Status Twitter account](https://twitter.com/msft365status).

You can also check the [Microsoft 365 Service health status page](https://status.office365.com/) (but this only works if the Microsoft login services are working.) Documentation around how to check the service status is available as part of [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/view-service-health?view=o365-worldwide).

For Azure-related issues you can check the official [Azure Support Twitter account](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) or the [Azure status page](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status).

If the issue is localised - then you should raise a support ticket in [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) or [Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/home/contact), otherwise wait for a resolution from Microsoft.